# Python zip() for n rows

Tags: python, list, python-3.x, merge

Given:
I have a table "Table 1" in `.xlsx` format with n number of rows having the values that are to be merged/zipped. For this example I am taking 4:

```
a,b,c,d
e,f,g,h
i,j,k,l
m,n,o,p
.
.
.
n
```

Another table "Table 2" in `.xlsx` format having number of rows to be zipped in Table 1. Suppose :

```
1,4
1,2
1,3,4
2,3,4
1,2,3,4
.
.
n
```

Expected Output:

```
a m,b n,c o,d p
a e,b f,c g,d h
a i m,b j n,c k o,d l p
e i m,f j n,g k o,h l p
a e i m,b f j n,c g k o,d h l p
```

I have tried:
Storing table 2 values in a list "table2Values" and table 1 values in a list "sheetData" and doing the following operation:

```
for l in table2Values:
    temp = sheetData[int(l)]
    c = 1
    if c > 1:
        listNew = [x + " " + y for x, y in zip(temp1, temp)]
        c += 1
    temp1 = temp

finalHeader = listNew
```

Above code works perfectly fine if the there are only two rows to be merged i.e there are only 2 values in my table2Values list. But, I am not able to figure out how to merge/zip more than two rows depending upon the values specified in table 2.

Comment: What would you expect the output for the example tables to be?

Comment: Scott Hunter, I have added it in the edit . Please review.

Comment: What happens when your code doesn't work? Do you get an error? Unexpected output?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming `table2Values` is a list of lists of numbers (from the example, `[[1,4],[1,2],[1,3,4],...`, and each row of `sheetData` is a list of characters (or just a string), this prints the desired strings:

```
for row in table2Values:
    print [" ".join(col) for col in zip(*[sheetData[i-1] for i in row])]
```

which yields (on the example data):

```
['a m', 'b n', 'c o', 'd p']
['a e', 'b f', 'c g', 'd h']
['a i m', 'b j n', 'c k o', 'd l p']
['e i m', 'f j n', 'g k o', 'h l p']
['a e i m', 'b f j n', 'c g k o', 'd h l p']
```